# Bulk insert with Doctrine 1.2

Tags: orm, insert, doctrine, performance, bulk

This code (source: http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/hu/component-overview:connection:flushing-the-connection)

```
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection();

$user1 = new User();
$user1->username = 'Jack';

$user2 = new User();
$user2->username = 'jwage';

$conn->flush();
```

is resulting 2 insert queries to be executed.

Is there a way to do this with only one bulk insert?

I think doctrine 2 is solving this problem (http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing), but it's still in beta.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Definatelly no this feature in v1, only v2.

Answer (score 6):

This post explains how to do it with Collections, as suggested by Michelangelo: [Doctrine - insert multiple rows with just one save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415725/doctrine-insert-multiple-rows-with-just-one-save)