# Doctrine - insert multiple rows with just one save()

Tags: php, database, insert, doctrine, save

How do I insert multiple rows into table calling `save()` method once in **Doctrine**?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add each record to a [`Doctrine_Collection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.2/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html) the call `save()` on the collection object.

```
$collection = new Doctrine_Collection('tablename');
$collection->add($record1);
$collection->add($record2);
$collection->add($record3);
$collection->add($record4);
$collection->save();
```

This only works if all the records are for the same table. Otherwise you're out of luck.

Comment: This is perfect! Inserting 1000 rows took only 3.8s instead of 76s!!

Comment: Is there anyway to get insert one record first and get id of it and add rest of it and insert all others

Answer (score 3):

Here another solution ,tested on Doctrine 1.2. 
No need to save each records, the flush() automatically finds out all the unsaved instances and saves them all.

```
$row = new \My_Doctrine_Record();
$row->name = 'aaa';
$row->approved = 1;

/// ...

$row = new \My_Doctrine_Record();
$row->name = 'val';
$row->approved = 'bbb';

Doctrine_Manager::connection()->flush();
```

Comment: I'm confused. You say there is no need to instantiate new records, but that's exactly what you are doing in your code when you repeatedly say `$row = new My_Doctrine_Record();`, right?

Comment: ops, I meant "no need to save each record". I'll change it

Answer (score 3):

If you use symfony2 it is so easy

```
// get the manager
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// enter the records
$em->persist($entitiy1);
$em->persist($entitiy2);
$em->persist($entitiy3);
$em->persist($entitiy4);
$em->persist($entitiy5);

// save the entries
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 2):

1)Declare all the tables.
2)Create the form.
3)Send to multiple tables.
4)Persist data.

```
use AppBundle\Entity\site;
use AppBundle\Entity\nba;
```

1)Declare all the tables.

```
 $site = new site;
 $nba = new nba;
```

2)Create form

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($site)




    ->add('site_id', IntegerType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
    ->add('category', ChoiceType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px'), 'choices' => $output))
    ->add('team', ChoiceType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px'), 'choices' => $nbat))
    ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => "Create",'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-success', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
    ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
```

3)Insert into multiple tables.

```
    {

        $site_id = $form['site_id']->getData();
        $category = $form['category']->getData();
        $team = $form['team']->getData();




        $site->setSiteId($site_id);
        $site->setCategory($category);
        $nba->setWinner($team);
```

4)Persist data

```
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($site);
            $em->persist($nba);
            $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look into the code of the "save" method of the Doctrine (1.2.x) "Collection.php" and all I saw is something like this:

```
foreach ($this->getData() as $key => $record) {
   $record->save($conn);
}
```

How should this ever insert all records with one mysql INSERT?

Comment: Your excerpt in Collection.php is wrapped by `$conn->beginInternalTransaction()` and `$conn->commit()`. That might explain it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but for example: MySQL MyISAM doesn't support transactions...