# Doctrine2 & Symfony2 single form insert in multiple tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony2's form with two fields: "A" and "B". I want to store them using Doctrine2 in two different tables.

I've already seen [Doctrine - insert multiple rows with just one save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415725/doctrine-insert-multiple-rows-with-just-one-save) but it's not my case.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved embedding a B field in A. [Watch here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)