# doctrine 1.2 performance, creating a large number of records (~5000)

Tags: php, mysql, performance, doctrine-1.2

Assuming **User** is a model which extends Doctrine_Record, consider the below (arbitrary) code that creates 5000 user records.

```
$conn->beginTransaction();

for ($i = 1, $i < 5001, $i++) {

    $user = new User();
    $user->some_field = $i;
    $user->save();
    $user->free(true);
}

$conn->commit();
```

I am finding that this script is timing out after 30 seconds and not managing to create all the Users.  Are there ways to optimize this code to work more quickly?  I am considering just writing regular old SQL to create the records but then I lose the power of the Doctrine_Record, including insert hooks etc (Note that this script times out even if there are NO hooks in the User model).

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try the `Doctrine_Collection` class, which allows bulk inserts :

```
$collection = new Doctrine_Collection('tablename');
$collection->add($record1);
$collection->add($record2);
$collection->add($record3);
$collection->add($record4);
$collection->save();
```

Comment: Your comment led me to another ticket that really helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415725/doctrine-insert-multiple-rows-with-just-one-save