# Updating multiple entries in Symfony

Tags: arrays, loops, symfony, foreach

In my Symfony project I want to update multiple database entries at once.

Starting point is this array of dates and values I want to update existing entries with:

```
$updates = Array ( [0] => Array ( [date] => 2007 [value] => 5 )
                   ...
                   [4] =>Array ( [date] => 2010 [value] => 8 ));
```

I get $date and $value with a foreach:

```
 foreach($updates AS $update)
 {
     $date = $update['date'];
     $value = $update['value'];
 }
```

My problem is to get [date] and [value] values from $updates to update the entries correctly. For some reason only the last array from $updates is taken when updating all entries like this:

```
           foreach($repo->customQuery($parameter1,..., $parameter5) AS $obj)
           {
               $obj->setThis($date)
                   ->setThat($value);
               $em->persist($obj);
           }
           $em->flush();
```

What am I missing? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is using one for loop instead of two foreach's.

```
    $statistic = (array with entities to be updated);
    $update = (array with new values);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($update); $i++)
    {
        $valStatistic = $statistic[$i];
        $valDate = $update[$i]['fromDate'];
        $valValue = $update[$i][$value];

        $valStatistic->setThis($valDate)
                     ->setThat($valValue);

        $em->persist($valStatistic);   
    }
    $em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on comments:

```
       foreach($repo->customQuery($parameter1,..., $parameter5) AS $obj)
       {
           $obj->setThis($date)
               ->setThat($value);
           $em->persist($ob); 
           $em->flush();
       }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue :(. But just for my understanding, using two foreach loops in the way described should work, right?

Comment: Thanks for your  follow-up, but as made clear with my edited question, the problem is that still only the last array from  $updates is taken to update all entries. When I print_r($date) inside the second foreach loop it shows all dates four times, so I suppose the combination of two foreach loops is the cause of the problem. Is there any other way of accessing ALL the values in an array than using a foreach? I tried array_map() but couldn't get it right.

Comment: I guess you could flush each time.  I'd give that a shot.  Edited above

Answer (score 0):

[Doctrine - insert multiple rows with just one save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415725/doctrine-insert-multiple-rows-with-just-one-save)

Just be careful of memory usage if you're going over a large data set.

Comment: It is nifty, but not what I needed :(