# Insert multiple rows with one query in Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have collections of clients, and every collection can contain many clients. This PHP code loops collections, and clients inside every collection. And saves the client to the database.

```
foreach ($collections as $key => $collection) {
      foreach ($collection as $k => $client) {
                 $name = $client['name'];
                 //...
                 $clientObj = new Client();
                 $clientObj->setName($name);
                 //..
                 $clientObj->save();
      }
}
```

What I want to do, is to group every collection in one Mysql query, then go to the next collection. Because the previous code executes one query per client, And for performance, we need one query per collection.

How can we do that?

Comment: Have already tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415725/doctrine-insert-multiple-rows-with-just-one-save)?

Comment: Thank you so much my dear for the reference , I'm gonna give it a try

Comment: Woow, thanks my dear, that works perfectly... You can add your comment as an answer, to make it best answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add each record to a [`Doctrine_Collection`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.2/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.Collection.html) the call `save()` on the collection object.

> ```
>  * Saves all records of this collection and processes the 
>  * difference of the last snapshot and the current data
> ```

As Example:

```
$collection = new Doctrine_Collection('client');
$collection->add($client1);
$collection->add($client2);
$collection->save();
```